# Determining Vector Given One Vector and the Angle Between the Two Vectors

Tags: vectors

If we have two vectors, A and B, and we know what vector A is and what the angle between A and B is, is there any way to determine the possibilities of vector B? (Assume the vectors are in two-dimensional space)

Comment: would not any vector on the surface of a cone fit this description?

Comment: assume the vectors are in two dimensional space

Comment: then it will be on either of one vector.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume a signed angle (e.g., counterclockwise is positive), then yes. If not, then no.

**From OP Comment**

If we know the length of $\vec{B}$ i.e., $|B|$, and the components of $\vec{A}$, then we can normalize A, left-multiply by the [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), then re-scale:

$$\vec{B}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta &\\\sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}\frac{|B|\vec{A}}{|A|}$$

If you don't know $|B|$, then set it to $1$ in the above formula to get the *direction* of $B$

Comment: Yes, assuming that the angle is signed.

Comment: Awesome, could you explain or give a link to why this works?

Comment: @pj6444 I did give a link. You're simply rotating A by $\theta$ then adjusting its length to B

Comment: Yes I see. Thanks for the answer it really helped

Comment: Great. Just make sure that theta should be in radians.